# How to Sync a C# Application in-memory object

Tags: .net, synchronization, wcf, nlb

I have a WCF service to be load balanced with NLB (Windows Network Load Balancer). So I need a Dictionary  object to be synced across all the instances of the WCF service.

What is the best possible way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

WCF Services are by nature, stateless.  You can turn on classic mode and use session, but session will have to be stored in the database.  You can share in-memory objects across servers.